# wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError in wand

Tags: nginx, imagemagick, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04, wand

When I am running my flask app using Nginx it works fine. But when I am using gunicorn and Nginx to deploy with real ip then it shows this problem. Ghostscript version is  **GPL Ghostscript 9.26** and ImageMagick version is **ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64**. Error is:
`wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError: MagickReadImage returns false, but did not raise ImageMagick  exception. This can occurs when a delegate is missing, or returns EXIT_SUCCESS without generating a raster.`

Code is given below:

```
from wand.image import Image as wi
file_path = 'filename.pdf'
output_directory = r'Modules/pdf_page_images/'
pdf = wi(filename=file_path, resolution=500)
pdfimage = pdf.convert("Jpeg")
page_number=1
for img in pdfimage.sequence:
    page = wi(image=img)
    page.save(filename=output_directory+'page'+str(page_number)+".jpg")
    page_number +=1
```

Full details of my error by **sudo journalctl -u project_name**:

```
জুন 03 19:46:58 nlp gunicorn[48237]: [2020-06-03 19:46:58 +0600] [48258] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48258
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]: [2020-06-03 19:48:10,108] ERROR in app: Exception on /get_text_from_pdf [POST]
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]: Traceback (most recent call last):
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     raise value
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/legal_ai2/ocr_server.py", line 68, in read_pdf_text
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     text_from_pdf = ocr.apply_ocr_on_pdf(r'UploadedFile/uploadedFIle.pdf')
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "Modules/ocr.py", line 152, in apply_ocr_on_pdf
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     pdf_to_image_converter.split_images_with_checked_checkbox(file_directory)
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "Modules/pdf_to_image_converter.py", line 33, in split_images_with_checked_checkbox
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     pdf = wi(filename=file_path, resolution=500)
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 8367, in __init__
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution,
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:   File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 8846, in read
জুন 03 19:48:10 nlp gunicorn[48237]:     raise WandRuntimeError(msg)
wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError: MagickReadImage returns false, but did not raise ImageMagick  exception. This can occurs when a delegate is missing, or returns EXIT_SUCCESS without generating a raster.
```

Comment: It's very difficult to say what's wrong with code we cannot see.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just added my code. Please take a look.

Comment: What is `wi()` please?

Comment: Sorry @MarkSetchell. This is "from wand.image import Image as wi"

Comment: I imagine the problem is that `wand` can't find you Ghostscript binary. So you need to first find the full path to it and secondly tell `wand`.

Comment: I would suspect that the system has run out of resources to continue PDF operations.